# Can I do something like this for get Entity by type name?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Can I do something like this for get Entity by type name?
I have many Entities and want to do the common method for getting.

```
try
{
     Type objectType = Type.GetType("Type." + type.ToString() + ", Assembly", true);
     data = _myDbContext.Set<objectType >.Where(w => w.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
     return data;
}
catch (TypeLoadException e)
{
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using the generic type in the `Set` method instead of worrying about reflection.

```
public TEntity GetById<TEntity>(int id)
    where TEntity : class
{
    return _myDbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Usage:

```
Account myAccount = Repository.GetById<Account>(69);
```

Comment: At first time I need get the right Entity by type name. 
It line _myDbContext.Set<objectType >